# Laravel methodnotallowedexception in combination with ajax (internal 500 server error)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So i try to increment a number in the database using ajax. Speed is important, i don't want a page refresh.

My Ajax

```
function giveRespect(username){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/increment",
    data: "name=" + username,
    success: function(msg){

    }
});
```

}
Note: where the username comes from is not important, that part works, i've tested this and it alerts the right username everytime, so the correct data is streamed into this method.

my Route:

```
Route::post('/increment', 'PostController@increment');
```

My controller method:

```
 public function increment(){
    DB::table('users')->increment('respect', 1, array('id' => $_POST['name']));
}
```

**Problem:** When i click to increment nothing happens, when i check INSPECT ELEMENT it says: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) `http://localhost:8000/increment`**

additional details: When i click on the link stated above, i get the nice laravel debug exception MethodNotAllowedException

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the proper way of retrieving values in laravel? You could try the following:

```
Input::get('username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by a friend of mine: The internal 500 server error came from:

```
$_POST['name']
```

it should have been:

```
Input::get('name')
```

oops :P